# Multiple calls to same $resource angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a factory service that looks something like this

```
app.factory('testService', ['$resource', function($resource){
  var test = $resource('/a/:action/:id/:subaction',{
    'getAll': {method: 'GET', params: {action: 'testAction'}}
  }
  return test;
}]);
```

and I am making two calls to this resource from my controller

```
test.getAll({}, callback1);
test.getAll({testParam: false}, callback2);
```

In this case callback1 is not getting fired and callback2 gets data from both calls.

Can anyone explain this behavior and the correct procedure to do this?

Comment: what is testParam in the parameters in the second call?

Comment: have you tried: test.getAll({}).$promise.then(callback1); ??

Answer (score 0):

From [Angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/%24resource) example:

```
var User = $resource('/user/:userId', {userId:'@id'});
     User.get({userId:123}, function(user) {
       user.abc = true;
       user.$save();
     });

var User = $resource('/user/:userId', {userId:'@id'});
     User.get({userId:123}, function(u, getResponseHeaders){
       u.abc = true;
       u.$save(function(u, putResponseHeaders) {
         //u => saved user object
         //putResponseHeaders => $http header getter
       });
     });
```

It's worth noting that the success callback for get, query and other methods gets passed in the response that came from the server as well as $http header getter function, so one could rewrite the above example and get access to http headers as:

i think you´re rewriting your callback, but stil making both request...

Try with promise:

```
var User = $resource('/user/:userId', {userId:'@id'});
     User.get({userId:123})
         .$promise.then(function(user) {
           $scope.user = user;
         });
```